# Switching regulator circuit failing

Tags: voltage-regulator, switching-regulator

I have a voltage regulator circuit which keeps failing.  It is based around a [switching regulator](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/max20077-max25277.pdf).  It takes 14V input from a variable voltage regulator (lab setup) and outputs 5V.  I see 14V on the input but 0V on the output.

Interestingly after I soldered this I checked the pads of the IC for shorts and I did not find any, but after powering everything I turned off the power and checked again and there were many shorts.  I replaced the IC, and the same thing happened again.  There must be something wrong with the circuit.

Particularly the voltage output to ground is showing just a few ohms.

Edit 1:

I have replaced the IC now twice.  Each time I measure no shorts from the Vout to ground.  As soon as I power the circuit once though, I measure shorts after powering down.  Just powered for a few seconds.  What could be happening?

[image: circuit]

[image: footprint]

[image: resistance check]

Comment: If it's an automotive design then the MAX20077 will fail quite often due to automotive surges etc.. It's only got a max rating of 36 volts and this is weedy compared to what line surge voltages you can get in automotive. Ignore if not automotive but, you should definitely state where the input source of power comes from.

Comment: Good point, let me update but right now I am testing with a variable voltage regulator so it should be a clean 14V.

Comment: What wire length between power source and your circuit? Has it ever worked (this bit's important to know). Where does the MOTOR_ON signal come from and, what is it connected to?

Comment: Minimal wire length I'd say 2ft.  This is the first time I am trying this circuit, no it has never worked.  The motorON signal comes from a multivibrator IC but I have verified that it is outputting 3.1V which is above the EN high threshold voltage.

Comment: How does the oscillogram look like before it fails? What’s your inductor peak current rating?

Comment: Circuit wise it looks good (cursory look)

Comment: O-scope shows a flat 0V on output and a flat 14V on the input.  Inductor saturation current for SRP3212-2R2M is 4.8A.   I think this is sufficient.  I don't understand why those pads are showing such low resistance to ground.

Comment: How are you powering it?  Wiring it up then enabling the power supply?  Or enabling the power supply (set to 14V DC out and some current limit I guess) then plugging it in?

Comment: Everything is wired up, the power supply is running but not yet controlling to 14V, then I enable it and it goes to 14V.  Current limit is 4A

Comment: I've had similar problems where a newly assembled PC board developed leakage paths and short circuits. I found that a thorough scrubbing with flux remover (alcohol), followed by detergent and clean water to remove ionic contaminants, and finally hot air, pretty much fixed the issue.

Comment: `flat 0V on output and a flat 14V on the input. Inductor saturation current for SRP3212-2R2M is 4.8A`, `[input] Current limit is 4A` Please edit everything inviting useful answers into the body of your question.

Comment: Is any load connected during these tests? Seeing \$V_{IL,EN}max\$ .6 V, I'd add a pull-down there(~.33M). (And pulse EN with 2\**soft start time* and low duty cycle, given the equipment.)

Comment: (I forget: With nothing connected to `MotorON`, beware LED D102 doubling as a photocell: Measure its current "driving" two series connected diodes when exposed to light.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot connect the SPS pin to the 14V input. This exceeds the absolute maximum of that pin:
[image]

To enable spread spectrum you could connect SPS to BIAS. For testing you could leave it floating for now or connect it to GND.

Obviously, up until now the IC has been getting damaged at the first turn on after soldering a new IC. To make troubleshooting easier I recommended testing with a lower current limit on your lab power supply. Make it only slightly higher than the current draw you are expecting. Disconnect any loads on the regulator IC output for now if possible.
A low current limit on the input voltage might prevent instant damage to the IC in case there are other issues at hand.

Comment: I rebuilt the circuit and made sure to never connect SPS to supply.  In this case I am now seeing an output voltage from the circuit around 5V.  But it becomes increasingly unstable as Vin increases.  This is a separate question though so I will ask it in a another question.